# List<MyClass> as datasource for DropDownList?

Tags: c#, list, .net-3.5, drop-down-menu, datasource

I have a simple Class with ID and Name on it which I would like to link to a DropDownList but it seems that `myDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";` and `myDropDownList.DataValueField = "ID";` are not accessible or available.

**UPDATE: I am using winforms**

```
public class Test
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

List<Test> myList = new List<Test>()
{
    // bla bla bla some entries bla bla bla you got the point.
};
myDropDownList.DataSource = myList;
```

I know I could override ToString but that would not help me with the value of each entry on the list.

**Are there any other options to print the Name on the dropdownlist while having another property as the value (ie: printing Name while having the selected value or item as the ID) ?**

Comment: Can you show us the markup where you set DatatextField/DataValueField? I have done what you describe many times and you are on the right track.

Comment: @n8wrl it doesnt even allow me to put it when I type myDropDownList. it doesnt have the option to auto complete to either of those. I am not sure what you meant by markup you mean the error when I try to use it on my dropdownlist ?

Comment: they are string parameters, auto complete will not work with them

Comment: that is just an issue with intellisense. This usually happens when you have a syntax error higher up physically in code. Check you code to see if it compiles atm.

Comment: @Matthew was setting it at the wrong place hehehe... Jonh's reply helped me see thru it, shame on me silly question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## For web based ASP.net

You need to specify the drop down lists `datatextfield` and `datavaluefield` properties.

```
MyDropDownList.DataSource = myList;
MyDropDownList.DataTextField="Name";
MyDropDownList.DataValueField="ID"; 
MyDropDownList.DataBind();
```

## For win form

You need to specify the `displaymember` / `valuemember` properties.

Just noticed this is a **winform** application try this:

```
MyDropDownList.DataSource = myList;
MyDropDownList.DisplayMember = "Name";
MyDropDownList.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Comment: @Prix no problem, I'm glad you solved it.  And no it wasn't a silly question, it was quite valid and something that other developers may forget :) or beginners may never know.

Comment: eheheh true, well I know I could use it but was setting it at the wrong place for the dropdownlist.