# I can't filling my dropdownlist from database using entity framework in c#

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

```
drpdwnGroupName.DataSource = (from y in db.Yetenek_grup
                                              select new

                                              {
                                                  y.yetenek_grubu
                                              }
                                            ).ToList();
```

Comment: You have to specify the `DataTextField and DataValueField and then call the DataBind()` for more info [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296651/2417602)

Comment: First Check , what framework are you using? second, have you checked that you can get a non empty list from your code?

Comment: i called databind in my code but it looks like  {yetenek_grubu = Windows} but i want it like only Windows